# Public and private id naming conventions

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-4, naming-conventions

We are storing these types of ids:

**our private id** - standard sql id, not shared with anyone else, usually called "id".

**our foreign keys** - refers to our private id, usually called "foo_id".

**our public id** - id generated by us for the purposes of passing to vendors.

**vendor public id** - id generated by vendor for the purposes of passing to other vendors (us).

Is there a naming convention for the last two?

I acknowledge that this could be opinion based, I'm interested in knowing if a convention exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the last two, but for the first two I would strongly advise that you give them the same names.

Using the name `id` in multiple tables is basically misleading.  Much better to have the primary key be `customerId` and the foreign key be `customerId`.  Then you know they are referring to the same key.  And in many databases, you can use a `using` clause for the `join`.

As for the last two, I would be fine with `vendorCustomerId` and `publicCustomerId`.  The latter would likely be whatever the customer expects, and that is fine.